# why do we need Callable classes in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the use of callable classes in dart lang? Following is the example code available on official dart site.

```
class WannabeFunction {
  call(String a, String b, String c) => '$a $b $c!';
}

main() {
  var wf = new WannabeFunction();
  var out = wf("Hi","there,","gang");
  print('$out');
}
```

How useful is it add a call function and call it using a class instead of creating a function itself in class

Answer (score 8):

This can be useful to make "named functions":

```
class _Foo {
  const _Foo();

  void call(int bar) {}

  void named() {}
}

const foo = _Foo();
```

Which allows both:

```
foo(42);
```

and

```
foo.named();
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically it's not that useful, but it's possible as a simple side effect of language design? It doesn't add anything we can't just as easily do a different way with the same amount of code, right?

Comment: @ThinkDigital Did you miss the last paragraph? :)

Comment: No, I read it, but I don't see a use case for that either. A static function is just as good it appears, unless I want to save some state within the function, which, at that point, is the same as any other Object

Comment: Functions already have names. I think the question is if there's a usecase for callable classes (callable instances, really) other than providing a single "shortcut" method.